# Как определить положение курсора относительно клиентского окна

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, координаты, курсор

При вызове функции `GetCursorPos()` получаю значения x и y положения курсора относительно размера монитора. Что можно использовать или как модифицировать функцию `GetCursorPos()` чтобы получать данные относительно клиентского окна, а не монитора?

[image: скриншот окна]

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию [MapWindowPoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints)

```
MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, my_window, p_point, 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!